# Trigger on difference between 2 date fields - not working

Tags: trigger, datetime, date, before-trigger

I'm a beginner in APEX and I'm trying to develop a trigger on Service Appointment that will auto populate the Work Duration field with the difference between the Schedule End date and Schedule Start Date field

I don't know how to have the difference (in hours) between these 2 fields auto-populate in Work Duration field

**The trigger**

```
trigger Change_Work_duration on ServiceAppointment (before insert, before update) {
    for (ServiceAppointment obj : Trigger.New){
    obj.Work_Duration_hrs__c = (obj.SchedEndTime.daysBetween(obj.SchedStartTime));
    
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, there is no method `daysBetween()` on the [`DateTime` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#!).

That method is part of the [`Date` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_daysBetween). Luckily, you can use the method `date()` to get a `Date` object from a `DateTime`, e.g.,

```
firstDateTime.date().daysBetween(secondDateTime.date());
```

... but that said, date and time work is complex. Two `DateTime`s may be on the same calendar day in one time zone, but not in another. When you use `date()`, you'll render the date in the time zone of the current user. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `date()` is a method you _call_ on your `DateTime` instance, the same way you were calling `daysBetween()` in your original code.